# Query Posts issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am a little unsure how to do a WP_Query to search a meta value of my posts. The meta data includes a persons height. So valid entries would be `5'9"` or `4'11"` and I need to do a Compare-Between.

To make it a bit clearer: I have a filter page. So the user can select the height between `4'0" - 5'9` or `5'9" - 5'11"`

The problem is I have the `'` and `"` symbols. I can remove these. But then it will be searching between `59` and `511` which is not going to work.

Anyone know of a work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the values in inches.

You could then set up a `WP_Query` or a [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) query to fetch your results.

Whenever you are displaying the values on the front end, you convert them back to feet and inches.

update:

```
function convert_to_feet( $input){
  $feet = (int) ($input/12);
  $inches = $input%12;
  return $feet . "'" . $inches . '"';
}

echo convert_to_feet(71);
```

Comment: How will I convert it back to Feet and Inches

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working that well, for example...
5'11"
5 Times 12 plus 11 = 71 
71 Divided by 12 is 5.9166666666....

Comment: Added a **simple** function that does the task. You should have type casted the result.